# Warning: Illegal string offset 'position' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMSS\login.php on line 57

Tags: php

This is my login.php

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please fill in the login details!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $query = "SELECT  email, password, position FROM user   WHERE   email = :email ";

    $query_params = array(':email' => $_POST['username'],);

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }

    //This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
    //we initialize it as false.
    $validated_info = false;
    $login_ok = false;

    //fetching all the rows from the query
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
        //compare the two passwords
        if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
            $login_ok = true;       
        }

    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
        if ($login_ok) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Login Successful!";
            $response["posts"]   = array();

                foreach ($row as $rerow) {
                $row = array(
                $post["position"] = $rerow["position"]
                            );

                array_push($response["posts"], $post);
                }

                die(json_encode($response));
        } 
        else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }

    } 
}   
else {
    ?>
    <h1>Login</h1> 
    <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
        Username:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        Password:<br /> 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
    </form> 
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

The Warning was appear three times and it also display

{"success":1,"message":"Login Successful!","posts":[{"position":"j"},{"position":"1"},{"position":"u"}]}

I enter my login id and password correctly and I want to retrieve the position which the value is "user" from my database, why It just show `j` `1` `u`.

Comment: line 57: `$post["position"] = $rerow["position"]`

Comment: The key/value pairs for arrays are set using `=>` and not just `=`

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, it got extra one error which is `Notice: Use of undefined constant position - assumed 'position' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMSS\login.php on line 57`

Comment: The previous `Illegal string offset` error is still showing?

Comment: ya the `Illegal string offset` still exist

Comment: @MonkeyZeus ,The extra errors previously I write wrongly, it suppose is `Notice: Undefined variable: post in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMSS\login.php on line 60` and line 60 is `array_push($response["posts"], $post);`

Comment: Before `foreach ($row as $rerow) {` try writing `$post = array();`

Comment: still the same error occur

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: post` error is still showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            $row = array(
            $post["position"] = $rerow["position"]
                        );
```

should probably be

```
            $row = array(
            $post["position"] => $rerow["position"]
                        );
```

In fact

```
        foreach ($row as $rerow) {
            $row = array(
                $post["position"] = $rerow["position"]
            );
            array_push($response["posts"], $post);
        }
```

Maybe you meant to do something else:

```
do {
    $post = $row["position"]
    array_push($response["posts"], $post);
} while ($row = $stmt->fetch());
```

This adds the field "position" to the posts, and continues fetching the other records.

Comment: I agree with your skepticism. If OP is looping `$row` and it has multiple elements then won't the loop stop after just one iteration because they are setting `$row` to a fresh array during the first iteration?

Comment: actually what I trying to do is that When I login with my email and password, Once it matched the login information, after that I need to retrieve the user position of user table. At the same time to validate user's position and determine which main menu that the Login.java will lead my user to..

Comment: because now I'm using PHP and by json data to pass the data to my Login.java for my mobile application.

Comment: @user3096526 added my interpretation of what you meant to do.

Comment: @JoopEggen but if I have several post like $post = $row["state"] , $post = $row["city"] and somemore , then I just add between the do{ and array_push($response["posts"], $post); ?

Comment: Maybe `array_push($response["posts"], $row);` - an array of arrays (records).

Comment: @JoopEggen okok thanks for the help and info. and wanna ask you that you know how to retrieve tag from php script and save in variable that declared in my android hava file.

Comment: Sorry not much opportunity to work for android. Ask a next question in stackoverflow.